# Copy conditional format when inserting new row

Tags: excel, vba, insert, conditional-formatting

I've created the code below to copy a template row of data that contains data validation and conditional format colors from a hidden sheet and insert it to a specific row.

The issue is everything works apart from the conditional format, all of the drop down cells remain white?

```
Sub Newstaff()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Code").Rows(4).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO1's").Range("A7").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert

End Sub
```

How do I change it so that when the new row is inserted it includes the colors from each of the conditions?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Code").Rows(4).FormatConditions` would reveal them, you could copy and pastespecial formats too.  Your code seems to work ok though.  What are the rules?

Comment: i tried this but it wouldn't work and kept debugging, the rule are when specific text is selected from drop down cells it changes the cell colour to the assigned text

Comment: but what do they relate to, is the sheet name in there, are they just to the template sheet etc?

Comment: sorry, they relate to the sheet PO1's were the row is being inserted, the template is a copy of one of the rows on it but going forward through the year i will have to insert the template line as i add people to it. all the CF was created on the PO1 sheet

Comment: The drop-down is not conditional formatting but data-validation. Check where the list-source is located.

Comment: the conditional format is what colour in changes to from the text selected from the datavalidation

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype, you can use PasteSpecial on the row you added, and paste the format

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO1's").Range("A7").End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)
```